# SQL to check list of value against a table column

Tags: sql

I have a table where the items in a column are logically grouped. I need to check a list of item is already exists on the table or not. I need to check for exact amount of list.

[image]

This is my table structure and if I search against my list ("Rick" and "Max), I should have get the group Id 2. But, if I only search by "Rick" I shouldn't get any result back.

Comment: What query are you using to do the searching? Also what kind of SQL are you using?

Comment: Why should you get no result when searching only for "Rick"?  That value has a `GroupId` in the table.  Are there additional criteria that you want to apply but have not described?

Comment: The whole purpose was to re-use an existing group. If input List of person doesn't belongs to any group, I will create a new group. So, it is necessary to identify the existing group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to fetch groups and names, using `GROUP BY` on `GroupId`, group names comma separated(**ordered**) and then check your input against it.

For example, in MySQL.

```
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT GroupId, GROUP_CONCAT(Name order by Name) AS "ConcNames"
   FROM my_table 
   GROUP BY GroupId) subQueryTable WHERE subQueryTable.ConcNames= 'Max,Rick';
```

Will give you:

```
------------------
GroupId  ConcNames
2        Max,Rick
```

Then check your parameter against `ConcNames` column(your input names should be **ordered** as well)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a8f1b/21)

Comment: And you should take into consideration the length limit for string fields, whatever that is...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with MySQL :

```
SELECT groupID,
       count(*),
  (SELECT group_concat(NAME separator ' and ')
   FROM TABLE_NAME table2
   WHERE table1.groupID=table2.groupID) RESULT
FROM TABLE_NAME table1
GROUP BY groupID
```

[image]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cc34/5

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question!

I'm sure there's a more elegant solution, but here's my recommendation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GroupID FROM test_table WHERE
    (name='Rick' OR name='Max') #... You could add more 'OR's here
    AND
    (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM test_table WHERE GroupID=(SELECT DISTINCT GroupID FROM test_table WHERE name='Rick')) # This only needs one name from the list
    =
    (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM test_table WHERE (name='Rick' or name='Max')) # The same WHERE clause as the first one
```

You would also need to make sure that only one row was returned.

As an example of how to use this, if you were working in PHP, given an array of names to check and a MySQL connection $con, you could do:

```
<?php

$names = array('Rick', 'Max'); // The names to check

$whereClause = '';
$index = 0;
foreach($names as $name) {
    if($index != 0) {
        $whereClause .= ' OR ';
    }
    $whereClause .= "name='{$name}'";
    $index++;
}

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT GroupID FROM test_table WHERE
({$whereClause})
    AND
    (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM test_table WHERE GroupID=(SELECT DISTINCT GroupID FROM test_table WHERE name='{$names[0]}'))
        =
    (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM test_table WHERE ({$whereClause}))";

$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$is_group = true;
$group_number = -1;
$n_groups = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $n_groups++;
    if($n_groups > 1) {
        $is_group = false;
    }
    $group_number = intval($row['GroupID']);
}

// The group number is now stored in $group_number, provided that $is_group == true.

?>
```

Hope I helped! I have validated the SQL code in my own MySQL database, but not the PHP code.